# Creating Android Apps only shows mobile website in WebView

Tags: android, appstore-approval, google-play

I am a .NET guy, so I am developing apps for WP7.

On Windows marketplace, they do not approve applications if it only opens a 
WebBrowser control and a mobile website in it. You have to write main functionality with Silverlight, C# and XAML.

For android I just want to use m.myapplication.com in a WebView control,
so as soon as you will open app it will show that url to you.

Will this application be OK for android market? Or will they require me to write
java code to fill the content?

P.S: I also wonder is there any basic android template that I can take for eclipse, and fill url for my mobile website, and it will run on my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "review" process for any apps that get uploaded to the market (other than checking to see that they are signed with a valid release key)

So yes you will be allowed to upload your app to the market. Even if it is just a webview pointing to a mobile site.

I know of no such template, but that doesn't mean that one doesn't exist. if you search around online for things like "Android WebView example" and have worked your way through the Hello World tutorial you should be able to implement your webview without too much hassle.